# rails before_save callback does not trigger

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I want to check an amount sent via a form before saving it to the DB. If the amount is too big, I want to set a boolean variable "confirmed" to false. Otherwise, its confirmed and true.

I entered this in my model:

```
  # if amount is too big, set to unconfirmed
  before_save do
    if self.amount > 9999
      self.confirmed = false
    else
      self.confirmed = true
    end
  end
```

Controller action (was scaffolded):

```
  def create
    @statement = Statement.new(statement_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @statement.save
        format.html { redirect_to thankyou_path, notice: 'Successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @statement }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @statement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Testing this results in the following:
- if the amount is < 9999, the form gets saved, all good.
- if the amount is > 9999, the form does not get saved. It simply stays on the same page and nothing happens. No error message and nothing to see in the log except the fact that the data did not get entered into the database.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Please share the controller code from where you are trying to save the data. Update in the question itself.

Comment: edited. that's a classic scaffold logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because if `amount` is greater than 9999, the value returned from block is `false` (from `self.confirmed = false` line) - and if block (or method) passed into `before_save` returns `false`, ActiveRecord stops saving the record. So the simple solution is to add `true` that would be returned:

```
before_save do
  if self.amount > 9999
    self.confirmed = false
  else
    self.confirmed = true
  end
  true
end
```

The relevant piece of documentation for reference:

> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as methods on the model, which are called last.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Canceling+callbacks